# Why is $R_p:T_pM\times T_pM \to \operatorname{Hom}(E_p,E_p)?$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, curvature

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $E\to M$ a vector bundle over $M$ and $\nabla:\Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(T^*M\otimes E)$ a connection on $E$.

The curvature $R$ of the connection is defined as $$R: \mathfrak{X}(M) \times \mathfrak{X}(M)  \times \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E)$$ with $$R(X,Y)s=\nabla_X\nabla_Y s - \nabla_Y\nabla_Xs - \nabla_{[X,Y]}s.$$

Now for any $p \in M$ why is $$R_p:T_pM\times T_pM \to \operatorname{Hom}(E_p,E_p)?$$

$R(X,Y)s$ evaluated at $p \in M$ should give $$(R(X,Y)s)(p)=R_p(X_p,Y_p)s(p)$$ where $X_p,Y_p \in T_pM$ and $s(p) \in E_p$ so how is this a map from $T_pM \times T_pM$ to $\operatorname{Hom}(E_p,E_p)$?

Comment: Because $R_p$ takes as input $(X_p,Y_p)\in T_pM\times T_pM$ and its output is the endomoprhism which takes $s_p$ and maps it to $(R(X,Y)s)(p)\in E_p$ where $X,Y,s$ are smooth extensions. If you’re asking about why the value of $R(X,Y)s$ at a point $p$ depends only on $X(p),Y(p)$ and $s(p)$ only, then that’s a standard argument by showing $C^{\infty}$ multilinearity in the various slots. So, it’s not clear to me whether your question is one of linear algebra(i.e the “currying” argument) or about manifolds and why the object $R$ defined on vector fields and sections gives a pointwise version.

Comment: I'm asking about the first sentence in your comment. It's not quite clear to me why $R_p$ is a map $T_pM\times T_pM \to \operatorname{Hom}(E_p,E_p)$. I can see that for two vector fields $X, Y$ in $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ at $p \in M$ we get $X_p,Y_p \in T_pM$, but I don't understand where the $\Gamma(E)$ disappears. I also know that $s(p) \in E_p$, but it still a mystery why evaluating the curvature at a point gives this map. @peek-a-boo

Comment: In general if we have vector spaces $V_1,\dots, V_k,W_1,W_2$, then a $(k+1)$-multilinear map $T:V_1\times\dots\times V_k\times W_1\to W_2$ is equivalent to a $k$-multilinear map $\tau:V_1\times\dots\times V_k\to\text{Hom}(W_1,W_2)$, simply by defining $[\tau(v_1,\dots, v_k)](w_1):=T(v_1,\dots, v_k,w_1)$. Apply this with $k=2$ and $V_1=V_2=T_pM$ and $W_1=W_2=E_p$, and $T$ is the originally induced map $T_pM\times T_pM\times E_p\to E_p$, and $\tau$ will be the desired $R_p:T_pM\times T_pM\to\text{Hom}(E_p,E_p)$ .

Comment: Is this the correspondence between multilinear functions and tensor fields? @peek-a-boo

Comment: My latest comment was just basic algebra, which if we were to boil down to basics says that a function $X\times Y\to Z$ is essentially the same as a function $X\to (Y\to Z)$. The correspondence between tensor fields (defined as sections of some bundle) vs $C^{\infty}$-multilinear maps is something else, called the ‘tensor characterization lemma’ or something to that effect, and this is what I breifly allued to in the second question of my first comment (which you said wasn’t really your question).

Comment: Thank you this made a lot of sense. @peek-a-boo